# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'set' and 'list' + more

Tags: python-3.x, replit

So I was working on [my friend's repl](https://replit.com/@LordPotashmallo/curly-ladle) for a school project, and it just stopped working because of this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/upm323671650/bare-imports.py", line 14, in <module>
    ".", extra_ignore_dirs=sys.argv[1].split()
  File "/tmp/upm323671650/pipreqs.py", line 98, in get_all_imports
    missing_modules = imports.keys() - (set(candidates) & imports.keys())
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'set' and 'list'
exit status 1


Replit: Package operation failed.
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfmga.png)

I can't access bare-imports.py or pipreqs.py, even if I enable hidden files. I don't see any ampersands(&) in my code anywhere.

I tried to search it up but I couldn't find anything relevant, so I come to y'all for help. No clue what it means.

Comment: I ran you repl and it seems to be working fine

Comment: So apparently, if I log out and run it, it also seems to work fine. It's only if I log in that it throws the error. Which is even more confusing. But, that means there is some way for it to work and run properly, so yeah...